# Parallel transport and geodesics in non-affine connections

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

How can one find Christoffel's symbols (and, so, visualise the parallel transport and geodesics) of conformal or projective connections of a manifold?

But my question is about the intuition standing behind these connections.

I know that we can "attach" a homogeneous space (a quotient Lie group) to each point of a manifold and define the parallel transport over a curve as a displacement over a curve tending to the identity of a homogeneous space if the parameter $t$ of a curve tends to the starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Ok... Imagine you're on a hilly hiking trail, which we'll call a manifold. Now, imagine you're trying to compare your walking stick (a vector) at different spots on the trail. In curved spaces like our trail, moving the stick from one spot to another could change its characteristics in some way. This is where a connection comes into play, it's like a rule book that tells us how to compare our walking stick at different spots on the trail.

An affine connection is like a rule book that makes sure certain things about the stick stay the same when we move it along the trail. For instance, it keeps the length of the stick and the angle it makes with the ground the same.

But what if we didn't want to keep everything the same? That's where other types of connections come in. A conformal connection is a rule book that only cares about the angle between the stick and the ground. It doesn't mind if the stick stretches or shrinks. Then there's a projective connection, which is even more relaxed. It only cares about whether the stick points in the same general direction. The stick can twist, stretch, or shrink, as long as it points along the same line.

These rule books, or connections, help us extend simple ideas from flat spaces, like the concept of a straight line or constant speed, to our hilly trail. The affine connection tries to keep as much the same as possible, while conformal or projective connections allow for more changes.

Lastly, imagine tying a small flat map (a homogeneous space) to every point on the trail. When you move the stick along the trail, you can imagine it moving on these little flat maps. Depending on the rule book you're using, the stick might keep its length and direction (affine), just its direction (conformal), or just its general line of action (projective).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, Gabriel! But I still have a few questions to ask. How can one imagine a geodesic of the conformal connection, say, on a 2-surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is given by taking in consideration the attachment of 2-spheres with the same mean curvature of a surface at the point of attachment?

Comment: Ah, I can see now. I perceived the attachment of spheres literally, but all that we do is map a (quotient) Lie group to a point on a manifold.